# Does javascript execute from top to bottom?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a lesson from codecademy and don't understand the order in which javascript executes.

I start with a Penguin constructor:

```
function Penguin(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.numLegs = 2;
}
```

// Then I create a Emperor class here and make it inherit from Penguin

```
function Emperor(name) {
 this.name = name;
}

Emperor.prototype = new Penguin();
```

// create an "emperor" object and print the number of legs it has

```
var me = new Emperor("John");

console.log(me.numLegs);
```

MY QUESTION: I was under the impression that I could define my object prior to the inheritance and still console log the numLegs property. Do I have to set the inheritance before I create any "empeor" objects? If so, does that mean javascript reads from top to bottom, because I've heard different things.

Comment: That is not a class. JavaScript does not have classes. It has prototype-based objects, not class-based objects. Also I've never seen this "inheritance" you speak of but I don't use JS prototypes much so that could just be me.

Comment: Your inheritance is wrong.  See http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-03/traditional-inheritance-in-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

Javascript statements are executed in the order they appear.

However, function declaration statements are hoisted to their containing scope, so their functions exist even before the statements appear.

Any statements that operate on a function (eg, the `prototype`) still run in normal order.

Comment: But if I move the me object prior to the inheritance, I can't console log me.numLegs, why is that?

Comment: @StackOverflow421: Because that code (`.prototype =`) didn't run yet.

Comment: so the only thing that gets hoisted up to global scope are function declarations and variables?

Comment: Function definitions do (the whole thing) and var declarations (without the assignment part), but NOT to the global scope, but rather to the top of the current scope (current function definition==those define scopes in JS). I.e, defining a function within a function won't make it a global function, but will make it available from the practically whole body of the parent function, even if the child function definition happened near the end of the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it, does execute from top to bottom.
Function definitions (doesn't apply to anonymous functions assigned for variables) and `var` declarations (not assignments, just declarations), however, are hoisted to the top of the current scope. (scopes in JS map to function definitions).

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on this and what you mean by assignments and declarations?

Comment: If you run a js file with `console.log(foo);`, it'll throw a Referrence error (foo is undefined). If you run `console.log(foo); var foo=5;`, it won't throw any errors because  the `var foo` gets hoisted to the top. It will log `undefined`, though, because only `var foo` (the declaration) gets hoisted. The assignment will still happen after `console.log`.

Comment: The hoisting thing is a weird quirk. IMO, it's better to not rely on it in any way.

Comment: got it totally makes sense and to be clear can you give me examples of what gets hoisted on top? is is just variables and any type of function?